# How to identify unicode character in C# as well as in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

When we can consider that string contain unicode character in C#:

- If ascii value greater than 127
- If ascii value greater than 255

I got below mentioned code for finding unicode character in C#. Can you please tell if it is correct?

Code :

```
string msg ="ref a Ã©"

if (msg.Any(c => c > 255))           
{
    Unicode = 1;
}
```

Here it will check ascii value greater 255 or what?.Any means any character in the string.

In SQL :

In table1 has `nvarchar` column `umsg` which contains unicode text.

I want to find out English text present in `umsg` column.

```
select * 
from table1 
where 
    RDate >='01/01/2014' and RDate < '09/26/2017' 
    and umsg = convert(varchar(max), umsg)
```

I think above message is unicode, if I used that, it/sql is showing me as English not unicode. Where am I doing something wrong?

Comment: AFAIK everything in C# is Unicode by default...

Comment: `umsg = convert(varchar(max), umsg)` I am not sure if I understood your snippets correctly, but `varchar` is **not** unicode, `nvarchar` is. Why do you convert it to non-unicode beforehand ? In this case, all will be ascii characters returned to your application, and therefore every character analized in your code will actually be detected as ASCII.

Comment: `string msg ='ref a Ã©'` - This does not compile. It is not valid C#, because C# uses double quotes for string delimiters, and single quotes for char delimiters (so they can contain only 1 char between them).

Comment: if your db only supports ASCII, do a round trip conversion with the ASCII encoding, see if the text changes.

Comment: @Peter ,I modified above my code.I is doble coat not single.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That convert function is product specific.)

Comment: Also note that there's no such thing as "ascii value greater than 127". ASCII is a 7-bit encoding.

Comment: I am using sql server 2012.

Comment: C# strings us the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set. NVARCHAR does, too. Something in the middle is corrupting your data. Character conversions aren't going to help much in determining the different characteristics of the text data.

Comment: Does this still need an answer?  If you need to check if all the characters in a string are valid in the [`Encoding.ASCII`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii(v=vs.110).aspx) encoding, see [.NET: How do I tell if an encoding supports all the chars in my string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/631426).